# Renamed etc directory Ubuntu 14.04, rolling back changes doesn't fix created issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, permissions

A friend told me he used to go around his VM Linux installs and break things to learn how things worked and to learn how to fix them. I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox Linked-Clone created for the purpose of breaking and fixing (and learning).

So the first thing I did was to rename the `/etc/` root directory with the Nautilus file browser running with root permissions.

I’ve got this far:

- Used a Live CD to rename the directory back to `/etc/`.
- While logged in as root from the Live CD: attempted to change ownership of `/etc/` to root.

Where I still need to go:

- The machine boots all the way to the login screen (which is why I was able to drop to terminal and try and use chown)
- I can log in, but Unity doesn’t start

Any ideas as to why changing it back didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

I found one fix:

1. DO NOT attempt to boot the machine from the install. (may have to hard shutdown the machine)
2. Boot the machine from the Ubuntu 14.04 live DVD.
3. Change the root directory of the live session to the root directory of the install.
4. Rename the directory back to etc.

Comment: The OP already states he has done this.

Comment: No. He hadn't done that at the time.